# How to resize matplotlib graph in tkinter window

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to set up some program that includes a matplotlib graph and tkinter buttons and whatnot below it. However, the matplotlib graph occupies the entire window overlaying the tkinter buttons and stuff.

I'd tried using pack, but it doesn't let me put stuff side by side, so I'd like the tkinter widgets to be arranged with .grid or coordinates.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import StringVar
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def eggs():
  print("eggs")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.title("eggs")


fig = Figure(figsize=(10, 6), dpi=100)
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,2,3,4]
AS = [10/2**0]
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x,y)
#fig.add_subplot(111).plot(AS)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

testbutton = Button(root, text = "test button", command = eggs)
testbutton.place(x=100, y=550)


root.mainloop()
```

Wanting the top part of the window to be occupied by the graph and the buttons and other additional stuff below it.

Comment: first try to use `grid()`. You can also group elements in `Frame` and inside use `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` to put elements horizontally, and outside use `place()`/`grid()`/`pack()`  to arrange Frames vertically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one `Frame` to keep graph and its toolbar vertically, and another `Frame` to keep buttons horizontally. And then you can use `pack()` to put one `Frame` at top top and other at the bottom.

---

The only problem makes `figsize=(10, 6)` which needs more space than `"600x600"`

---

BTW: you can use `Button(toolbar, ...)` to add button to `NavigationToolbar2Tk` - see `"my tool"`.

---

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2IYb.png)

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- functions ---

def eggs():
    print("eggs")

# --- main ---

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
AS = [10/2**0]

# ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.title("eggs")

# ---

frame_top = tk.Frame(root)
frame_top.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

fig = Figure(dpi=100) # figsize=(10, 6), 
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x,y)
#fig.add_subplot(111).plot(AS)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame_top)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, frame_top)
toolbar.update()

tool = tk.Button(toolbar, text="my tool")
tool.pack(side='left')#, fill='x', expand=True)

# ---

frame_bottom = tk.Frame(root)
frame_bottom.pack(fill='x')

button1 = tk.Button(frame_bottom, text="button1")
button1.pack(side='left', fill='x', expand=True)

button2 = tk.Button(frame_bottom, text="button2")
button2.pack(side='left', fill='x', expand=True)

button3 = tk.Button(frame_bottom, text="button3")
button3.pack(side='left', fill='x', expand=True)

# ---

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Didn't know you can simply add a button to toolbar... +1.